# Do we need to use the 99s in html5 like id="name"

Tags: html

I have seen that people use `<div id=name>` rather than `<div id="name">`

is that something we should do in html5 or is it simply a personal choice

Thanks

Comment: @Maciej: the fancy angled quotes in the question title are collectively referred to as 66's and 99's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. HTML specs require quotes. The regular `"` and `'` characters. The 66's and 99's are a typographic abberation and MAY be supported by some browsers, but they're not part of the HTML spec and normally wouldn't not be treated the same as `"` and `'`.

Comment: HTML mandates only in certain situations (as XHTML is XML it mandates always). See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2 . I haven't found any paragraph in HTML 5 but here is an example without  (in 3.5.2): http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#common-microsyntaxes .